# sliders value are resetted after click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am currently using some javascript code via chrome console to automate some tasks on a website.

The webpage have multiple element, each element contains two sliders and this is the HTML code

```
<div class="ewok-buds-sliders">
    <div class="ewok-buds-slider" style="width: 50%;" id="ewok-buds-validation-slider-left-0-0">
        <div class="evl-slider2">
            <div class="evl-slider2-visible-area" style="margin-left: 8.333333333333334%; margin-right: 8.333333333333334%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="slider1" class="evl-slider2-value-field" value="0">
                <div class="evl-slider2-label">Slider1</div>
                <div class="evl-slider2-slider evl-slider2-green goog-slider goog-slider-horizontal">
                    <div class="evl-slider2-bar-selectable"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-bar-selected" style="width: 0%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-thumb evl-slider2-thumb-value goog-slider-thumb" style="left: 0%;">
                        <div class="evl-slider2-thumb-triangle"></div>
                        <div class="evl-slider2-thumb-divider"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 0%;" data-tick="N/A"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 20%;" data-tick="FailsM"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-small" style="left: 30%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 40%;" data-tick="SM"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-small" style="left: 50%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 60%;" data-tick="MM"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-small" style="left: 70%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 80%;" data-tick="HM"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-small" style="left: 90%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 100%;" data-tick="FullyM"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ewok-buds-slider" style="width: 50%;" id="ewok-buds-validation-slider-left-0-1">
        <div class="evl-slider2">
            <div class="evl-slider2-visible-area" style="margin-left: 8.333333333333334%; margin-right: 8.333333333333334%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="slider2" class="evl-slider2-value-field" value="0">
                <div class="evl-slider2-label">Slider2</div>
                <div class="evl-slider2-slider evl-slider2-purple goog-slider goog-slider-horizontal">
                    <div class="evl-slider2-bar-selectable"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-bar-selected" style="width: 0%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-thumb evl-slider2-thumb-value goog-slider-thumb" style="left: 0%;">
                        <div class="evl-slider2-thumb-triangle"></div>
                        <div class="evl-slider2-thumb-divider"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 0%;" data-tick="N/A"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 20%;" data-tick="Lwst"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-small" style="left: 30%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 40%;" data-tick="Low"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-small" style="left: 50%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 60%;" data-tick="Med"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-small" style="left: 70%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 80%;" data-tick="High"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-small" style="left: 90%;"></div>
                    <div class="evl-slider2-tick-big" style="left: 100%;" data-tick="Hghst"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in javascript, I am using this code to get the pair of sliders inside a specific element and set for each slider a specific percentage and hidden value.

```
const hiddenValue = "4";
const percentage = "80%";
let sliders = elements.getElementsByClassName("evl-slider2"); //no problem here, I can get correctly the elements of the page that I need with the sliders, so I iterate for each element.
for(let s = 0; s<sliders.length; s++){
    block = sliders[s];
    let k;

    let sliderBar = block.getElementsByClassName("evl-slider2-bar-selected");
    let sliderTriangle = block.getElementsByClassName("evl-slider2-thumb evl-slider2-thumb-value goog-slider-thumb");
    let hiddenField = block.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"].evl-slider2-value-field');
    
    for (k = 0; k < sliderBar.length; k++) {
        sliderBar[k].style.width = percentage;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < sliderTriangle.length; k++) {
        sliderTriangle[k].style.left = percentage;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < hiddenField.length; k++) {
        hiddenField[k].value = hiddenValue;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, after setting a value for the sliders with this code if I click with my mouse on the slider1 to set a value, the value on the element `<input type="hidden" name="slider2" class="evl-slider2-value-field" value="0">` on the second slider is settet again to 0.

How can avoid the second slider hidden value from being reset to 0?

Comment: Can you add also your css otherwise we cannot fully reproduce your code.

Comment: the website is not mine, how can I add the CSS? @atteggiani

Comment: If the website is not yours how are you changing the website in the first place?? 

Just from the code you shared it's not possible to reproduce your error. I cannot see any slider, only two writings (Slider1 and Slider2).

Comment: Given that your console-code doesn't have any event handlers, and changing one element changes a different element - there's probably some code on the page that "resets" the other sliders based on the one that you've just changed.  You'll need to find that code and discombobulate it.

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for your answer. can you give me some hints on how to track these changes? The page code seems very complicated at first glance

Comment: "*give me some hints on how to track these changes*" - search through the page's JS for those element classes and IDs.

Comment: Maybe you could trace through the page's JS and find whatever is doing that change, and selectively, surgically counter it.  Or go the brute force approach, and just remove event handlers for all likely events (`click`, `change`, etc) on all of those elements.  You might unintentionally disable other functionality you want with the brute force approach though.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that, after setting a value for the sliders with this code if I click with my mouse on the slider1 to set a value, the value on the element  on the second slider is settet again to 0.

You can create an array where you will store the items that were changed by the user. Each time an item is changed by the user, store something that identifies the item (perhaps its index) in your array. Then, convert your code into a function:

```
function something() {
    const hiddenValue = "4";
    const percentage = "80%";
    let sliders = elements.getElementsByClassName("evl-slider2"); //no problem here, I can get correctly the elements of the page that I need with the sliders, so I iterate for each element.
    for(let s = 0; s<sliders.length; s++){
        block = sliders[s];
        let k;

        let sliderBar = block.getElementsByClassName("evl-slider2-bar-selected");
        let sliderTriangle = block.getElementsByClassName("evl-slider2-thumb evl-slider2-thumb-value goog-slider-thumb");
        let hiddenField = block.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"].evl-slider2-value-field');
    
        for (k = 0; k < sliderBar.length; k++) {
            if (yourarray.indexOf(k) >= 0) sliderBar[k].style.width = percentage;
        }

        for (k = 0; k < sliderTriangle.length; k++) {
            if (yourarray.indexOf(k) >= 0) sliderTriangle[k].style.left = percentage;
        }

        for (k = 0; k < hiddenField.length; k++) {
            if (yourarray.indexOf(k) >= 0) hiddenField[k].value = hiddenValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if it was a `click` event that caused the turmoil, then create another click event, such as:

```
yourItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTimeout(something, 200);
});
```

which will restore the state of the items that were not yet changed by the user.